# Using diff-highlight with Git GUI

Tags: linux, git, git-gui

Is there a way to use [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight) with [git gui](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui)?

The extra highlighted info is invaluable when comparing lines that only changed a bit, and while using diff-highlight from the terminal (described here: http://coderwall.com/p/ydluzg/better-git-diff) is great, when I'm trying to make sense of large changes, I really like using the gui.

It doesn't look like there's much of a way.
I tried editing the Additional diff parameters in the gui and hacking on something like `| diff-highlight`, but that was no good.

Also worth noting: using `--color-words` is not a good workaround.
First, [it breaks git gui](http://neurotap.blogspot.com/2012/04/character-level-diff-in-git-gui.html). Second, the diff output isn't nearly as easy to read as that of a normal diff processed through diff-highlight.

Comment: [Visualization of intraline differences](https://github.com/prati0100/git-gui/issues/31), this is the issue/feature you want in the `git-gui`'s github code repo.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a standalone diff/merge app. Like Beyond Compare: https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs
 or winmerge: https://coderwall.com/p/76wmzq/winmerge-as-git-difftool-on-windows , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881594/use-winmerge-inside-of-git-to-file-diff .

That will serve you much better. git-gui is a little Tcl/Tk afterthought app that's never going to get developed into anything more.

You can and also try to use one of the big IDE-s. Most of them know how to handle GIT and use their own diff modules.

Comment: With `git gui`, user can select some lines to `stage` them, while for other standalone dif/merge tools, they don't have such feature.

Comment: git gui is a glorious tool, not an afterthought ;_;